# Add exception to scroll

Tags: jquery, scroll, anchor

I have this code in my header which scrolls the page to a specific anchor, but this code scrolls all my pages. I want to add an exception to my HomePage. How can i do that? Thx!

```
//this code is between <head> tags in my header file.
<script
function scroll(){
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $('#scroll').offset().top
    }, 1000);

}
</script>

//this code is at the bottom of the page in my header file
//anchor
<a href="#scroll" id="scroll"></a>

//this code is in the header file
//called
<body onload="scroll()">
```

Comment: Hmmm... don't add the code to your HomePage?

Comment: Are you using a CMS? Or any other application?

Comment: I am using wordpress

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the code to work on a certain page, then don't add the javascript to that page, or don't call the function.

However, the code you posted on its own doesn't do anything, it's just a function (you don't show where it's called), and your question is formulated rather vaguely so I had to guess what you want exactly. So I really don't have enough information to give a more specific answer.

Comment: What do you mean "not an answer"? See the first line of what I wrote, I do think it answers the question asked.

Comment: That my friend is a comment. Not an answer.

Comment: Seems like an answer to me.

Comment: See the first comment to the question. How is your "answer" any different to that?

Comment: For one, since I haven't really used this site before, I don't have enough reputation to comment. Second, I don't follow with your logic. I thought the purpose of an "answer" was to "answer" the question that was asked in the original post? And since the question was "how can I not run the code on my homepage" I answered how to do that. The second part of my answer could have been a comment as well, since it "comments" on the question. But, and correct me if I'm wrong, as far as I can tell I did answer the question.

Comment: The code is in my header, i dont know how it works, but it works. I just want to add an exception for my homepage. I dont know exactly what you dont understand.

Comment: @ElviraEmm the code you provided is a function "scroll()". In order for this code not to be run, you have to remove the part of your webpage that calls for this function. This could be something like `<body onload="scroll();">` where you simply remove the `onload="scroll"` on the pages where you don't want it executed.

Comment: If i remove that line, the scroll will stop working on all my pages.

Comment: so, do you have any ideas?

Comment: Basically you should remove it on the pages that you don't want it to happen, but keep it on the other pages.

Comment: how to do that? I am new in web development